# Parse.Router cannot find reference files when deep link

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, parse-platform, routes, backbone-routing

I've been slowly finding my way through building a single page website using parse.js, which includes Parse.Router.

Today I finally overcame the issue where clicking the browser refresh button caused a 404 error by modifying my .htaccess file.

The issue I'm facing now is that if I navigate to say "localhost/root/profile/edit" and then click the browser refresh button, my page is found OK, but none of my resources load correctly. In fact, I get this error in my console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I can see in the console that it is trying to load my files from "localhost/root/profile/js/file.js" instead of from where they're located in my root directory. The odd thing is that when I click refresh at "localhost/root/profile" everything loads up just fine. Just one level deeper and it doesn't work.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

    RewriteRule (.*) index.php
</ifModule>
```

Here is my app.js file, loaded in my main index.php file:

```
// app.js
$(function() {
    Parse.$ = jQuery;

    Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

    // * ---------
    // * Root View
    // * ---------
    var RootView = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#root-tpl').html()),
        events:{
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template());
        }
    });

    // * ------------
    // * Profile View
    // * ------------
    var ProfileView = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#profile-tpl').html()),
        events: {
            'click .edit-profile': 'edit'
        },
        edit: function(){
            Parse.history.navigate("profile/edit", true);
            return false;
        },
        render: function(){
            var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
            this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        }
    });

    // * ------------
    // * Edit View
    // * ------------
    var EditView = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#edit-profile-tpl').html()),
        render: function(){
            var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
            this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
        }
    });

    // * ------------
    // * Parse Router
    // * ------------
    var MyRouter = Parse.Router.extend({
        initialize: function(options){
            this.user = Parse.User.current();
            $("body").on("click","a:not(a[data-bypass])",function(e){
                // block the default link behavior
                e.preventDefault();
                // take the href of the link clicked
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                // pass this link to Parse
                Parse.history.navigate(href,true);
            });
        },      
        start: function(){
            Parse.history.start({
                root: App.ROOT,
                pushState:  true,
                silent:     false
            });
        },
        routes: {
            "":             "root",
            "profile":      "profile",
            "profile/edit": "editProfile",
            "*nf":          "notFound"
        },
        root: function() {
            var rootView = new RootView();
            rootView.render();
            $('.main-container').html(rootView.el);
        },
        profile: function() {
            if (this.user) {
                var profileView = new ProfileView({ model: this.user });
                profileView.render();
                $('.main-container').html(profileView.el);
            }  else {
                this.navigate("root", {trigger: true});
            }
        },
        editProfile: function() {
            var editView = new EditView({ model: this.user });
            editView.render();
            $('.main-container').html(editView.el);
        },
        notFound: function() {
            console.log("in the not found");
        }
    }),
    var App = {
        ROOT: "/root/",
        router: new MyRouter()
    };
    App.router.start();
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I came up with a poor way to partially fix. I added php to the top of my index.php that creates a variable based on the depth of the url. Say my url is "host/root/profile/edit", I'd calculate the depth to be 3 (which is the deepest I'll likely be going). With that info I create a var named $dots and assign it a value of "../". I then append that to all of my asset files like `<link href="<?php echo $dots; ?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`. This still doesn't fully work though. After a page refresh I end up with some broken images among other things I'm sure. Still working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with my src paths for my source files.

I was requesting my source files like:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

when I should have been requesting them like:

```
<link href="/root/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Once I made this adjustment everything now seems to be working as expected.